# Grails Spring Securiy Oauth Provider plugin: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: grails, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-provider

I am using grails "Spring Security OAuth Provider" plugin. And I am able to get **access code** on response of below URL.

```
http://localhost:8080/oauthServer/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=test_client&scope=read&redirect_uri=http://example.com?
```

But when I send the request to get **access token** by **access code** using below URL, I am getting "**Full authentication is required to access this resource**" error message.

```
curl -header "Authorization: Basic bnVkZ2VDbGllbnQ6YjRkNzA3NmE3YTA4N2E4MWMzMTE2ZjZlNWQzZWY0MDJjNmQ4ZjM3Nw==" http://localhost:8080/oauthServer/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=kuH8aC
```

**Note:** `base64(client_id:client_secret)=bnVkZ2VDbGllbnQ6YjRkNzA3NmE3YTA4N2E4MWMzMTE2ZjZlNWQzZWY0MDJjNmQ4ZjM3Nw==`

The full error message is given below.

```
<oauth>
 <error_description>
   Full authentication is required to access this resource
 </error_description>
 <error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

What I am missing. Please suggest.

Thanks

Update 1

Actually I am following the [this documentation](http://bluesliverx.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/docs/guide/index.html) of Spring security oauth provider plugin.

There is my configuration setting.

```
// Added by the Spring Security OAuth2 Provider plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.clientLookup.className = 'com.oauth.Client'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.authorizationCodeLookup.className = 'com.oauth.AuthorizationCode'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.accessTokenLookup.className = 'com.oauth.AccessToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.refreshTokenLookup.className = 'com.oauth.RefreshToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false

//grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/client/index'

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.auth.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.auth.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.auth.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/oauth/authorize.dispatch':      ["isFullyAuthenticated() and (request.getMethod().equals('GET') or request.getMethod().equals('POST'))"],
    '/oauth/token.dispatch':          ["isFullyAuthenticated() and request.getMethod().equals('POST')"],
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = [
        'clientCredentialsAuthenticationProvider',
        'daoAuthenticationProvider',
        'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
        'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider'
]

grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password', 'client_secret']

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        '/oauth/token': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',
        '/securedOAuth2Resources/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',
        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter'
]
```

My controller is default one.

```
@Secured(["#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')"])
    def clientRoleExpression() {
        render "client role expression"
    }

    @Secured(["ROLE_CLIENT"])
    def clientRole() {
        render "client role"
    }

    @Secured(["#oauth2.clientHasAnyRole('ROLE_CLIENT', 'ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')"])
    def clientHasAnyRole() {
        render "client has any role"
    }

    @Secured(["#oauth2.isClient()"])
    def client() {
        render "is client"
    }

    @Secured(["#oauth2.isUser()"])
    def user() {
        // code
    }

    @Secured(["#oauth2.isUser()"])
    def getSubscriptionDetail() {
       //code
    }

    @Secured(["#oauth2.isUser()"])
    def getHistory(){
        //code 
    }

    @Secured(["#oauth2.denyOAuthClient()"])
    def denyClient() {
        render "no client can see"
    }

    @Secured(["permitAll"])
    def anyone() {
        render "anyone can see"
    }

    def nobody() {
        render "nobody can see"
    }

    @Secured(["#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT') and #oauth2.isClient() and #oauth2.hasScope('trust')"])
    def trustedClient() {
        render "trusted client"
    }

    @Secured(["hasRole('ROLE_USER') and #oauth2.isUser() and #oauth2.hasScope('trust')"])
    def trustedUser() {
        render "trusted user"
    }

    @Secured(["hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.hasScope('read')"])
    def userRoleOrReadScope() {
        render "user role or read scope"
    }
```

Comment: Which grails version are you using? I think you should provide full authentication to your action.

Comment: Need more info. Post your config, routing and controller.

Comment: How did you resolve this?, I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your token endpoint configuration requires that the request be POST. Unless there's more to your curl command than shown above, you need to have something like

```
curl -X POST
```

in addition to your --header option.

Answer (score 0):

I did not know the exact reason for this issue but this issue is not in the latest version of the plugin. Please use latest version of this plugin.